# Target specific img nested inside <span data-src> with css

Tags: html, css

I have pictures nested inside a SPAN tag from a plugin.

```html
    <div class="grid">
       <span data-picture>
          <span data-src="img/pictures1.png"></span>
          <span data-src="img/pictures2.png"></span>
          <span data-src="img/pictures2.png"></span>
       </span>
    </div>
```

Is it acceptable to write a CSS rule targeting png file, like this?

```css
    span[data-src^="img/"] {
       -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
       filter: grayscale(1);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it to see? I'm having a hard time understanding how a `<span>` tag would display an image as if it were an `<img>` tag.

Comment: you can as well do : `span[data-src$=".png"]` to select any  whatever.png  ........................Beside, maybe you should explain how your plugin works to clarify your question and eventually what is in fine generated in your TML ... because here, your filter could be applied to div.grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector works but I don't know why on earth you would do such a thing ? If you are trying to show this as an image it is a bad idea. Think about accessibility issues and possibly javascript not working properly.

```css
span[data-src^="img/"] {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: tomato;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
   <span data-picture>
      <span data-src="img/pictures1.png"></span>
      <span data-src="img/pictures2.png"></span>
      <span data-src="img/pictures2.png"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```